# Question about general direction of development of application of Tensor Networks to AdS/CFT

Tags: condensed-matter, quantum-entanglement, ads-cft, tensor-network

I am quite interested in the area of application of Tensor Networks(TNs) to AdS/CFT correspondence. I would like to clarify certain points in order to get better general picture.

- What is   the main object of this research?
  Is it to show that AdS/CFT correspondence can be derived  as continuous(or may be some other) limit of certain kind(s) of TNs?
- What  would be the sufficient condition of equivalence between certain continuous limit of TN and AdS/CFT?
- Future prospects: Suppose one was able to show that AdS/CFT may be obtained from TNs. Would it mean that one can in principle obtain TN formulation of String theory?

Comment: "*One interesting possibility of explaining the mechanism of holography is its possible connections to tensor networks.Tensor networks are methods to express quantum wave functions in terms of network diagrams and are in a very similar spirit of holography because it geometrizes algebraically complicated quantum states. In the pioneering work [3], it has been conjectured that the AdS/CFT correspondence may be interpreted as the MERA (multi-scale entanglement renormalization ansatz) network.*" See [From Path Integrals to Tensor Networks for AdS/CFT](https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.04645).